# How to get `Type` of Angular object?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a function that takes in an Angular `Type`, and constructs a component object of that `Type`:

```
createThing(kind: Type<any>) {
    // create a new component of Type kind
}
```

that is a pretty minimal wrapper on `ViewContainerRef.createComponent` and basically follows [this example](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader).

Anyhow I am trying to define a method in a parent class `Parent`, that calls `createThing`, but I want to create a thing of type `Child`.

So, for example:

```
class Parent {
    ...
    clone() {
        createThing(this.Type)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, `this.Type` is not a thing.  `typeof this` returns a `string`.  I need to get the Angular `Type` of the current (or an arbitrary) object.  How do I get the `Type` at runtime?

Comment: You can't, basically. Types are stripped away during transpilation. With classes, you have the `instanceof`, but that doesn't let you ask what type something is.

Comment: Well, I think that `Type` is not a "typescript type", it's a javascript `class`... probably should probably be called `Class` instead of `Type`.

Comment: [Angular `Type`](https://angular.io/api/core/Type).  I've tried to just pass in `this.constructor` as well, which I expected to work, but this generates compile time errors about signatures.

Comment: You could control the return type of `createThing()` via generics. Is that what you're wanting to do?

Comment: @BrandonTaylor this still leaves me having to re-define the `clone` method for each `Child` class

Comment: `clone() { createThing<Child1>() }`.... `clone() { createThing<Child2>() }` ....

Comment: You could use a string to class object to pass to clone. This way you only have to scale your map instead re-defining the function

Comment: @BrandonTaylor like [this](https://gist.github.com/arniebradfo/2b163acbb51c5f0e7806acdd35906998)?

Comment: mmmmmm, then I could `clone(classLookupMap[typeof this])`

Comment: I haven't used that in particular, but yes, that's the idea